Do Randomly Chosen Small Circuits Behave like PRGs?
I'm wondering how common PRGs are among the set of all functions by considering the following heuristic.
Let $n(k)\in\mathsf{poly}(k)$ be some function, and set $k$ to be an input size. Consider all circuits of size $n(k)$ which have input length $k$ and output length $k+1$. Furthermore, we enforce a depth criterion: while it is believed that PRGs exist even in $\mathbf{NC}^{0}$, to avoid dealing with pathological counterexamples (like circuits which simply xor the last two bits, for instance), we force the circuit to be at least log-depth.
Suppose I select a circuit from this set at random. Is this circuit likely to exhibit PRG-like behaviour? I'm being purposely vague as to what I mean by 'PRG-like,' but it's something to the effect of "at the very least, simple distinguishers are hard to find".
Note that the assertion is false  if $n$ is very small -- if we take $n(k) = k$, for instance. However, assuming that $n$ is at least $k^{1+o(1)}$, is it true that randomly selected functions behave pseudorandomly in this manner? If not, is there some natural distribution of circuits that is likely to yield only PRGs?

This is a great question! I fear it's a highly nontrivial one, though, but I will think about it. The original title "Do Randomly Chosen Functions Behave like PRGs?" was slightly misleading: a random function behaves obviously as a PRG. It's now clear the question asks specifically about random small circuits, which is very different. [Edited by moderator to reflect change to the title]

The question does not precisely define what a circuit of size $n$ with $k$ inputs and $k+1$ outputs is, and the answer depends on that.
First, take that as: a series of $n$ two-input NAND gates with inputs constrained to be distinct and from the $k$ inputs or earlier-defined gates, and the outputs from the $k+1$ last gates (or last inputs for $n\le k$). This does not yield a PRG (argument: in general, outputs are biased for random input, because if that was not, the next defined gate would output 1 with 75% probability).
Using NAND-or-NOR gates does not fix this (the same argument can be extended).
Restricting to 3-inputs balanced non-linear gates such that $f(a,b,c)=(a\land b)\oplus(\bar a\land \bar c)$ markedly improves on that, however there's still the possibility that an output is biased (argument: some assemblies of two such gates are unbalanced). Thus I fear we'd need $n(k)$ exponential to make bias undetectable.

I think we can construct a suitable class of $(k(k-1))^n$ circuits (some equivalent) as follows:

Define $S_k$ as the XOR of the $k$ inputs $S_0$ to $S_{k-1}$
For $i$ in $[0,n)$

pick two distinct indices $u,v$ in $(i,i+k]$
define $S_{i+k+1}=(S_u\lor\overline{S_v})\oplus S_i$


Outputs are the $k+1$ values $S_n$ to $S_{n+k}$

Rationale (not a full argument; much less a proof): step 2 implements an $n$-rounds asymmetric Feistel cipher of the $k+1$-bit state defined at step 1 and output at step 3. For large enough $n$, step 2 can be modeled as a public pseudorandom (even) permutation, and security of the resulting PRG follows.

Tentative conclusion: For many natural definitions of a circuit of size $n$ with $k$ inputs and $k+1$ outputs, a random such circuit of size polynomial in $k$ is not a PRG (even adding the restrictions proposed in the question). However we can define subclasses of such circuits where that holds, and that can be randomly sampled with ease.
